# MIPS program for area of a square

Tags: assembly, floating-point, conditional-statements, mips, low-level

I need to write a program to find the area of a square (in floating point decimal) where all calculations are done through function calls. I've executed the program step by step and loaded into the register $f0 is the value that should be the result I need, however it keeps printing out the area value of 1.

To clarify, the usage of the program is as followed:

```
enter x1
enter x2
enter y1
enter y2
```

do calculation for change in x, and change in y, then add them
Square that number (to find the distance)
go to the function for calculations of area for a square (r^2)

and the code is as followed:

```
# A program to demonstrate function calls

    .data   # Data declaration section
    prompt: .asciiz "\n Please enter an integer "
    result1: .asciiz "\n Side 1 is: "
    result2: .asciiz "\n Side 2 is: "
    result3: .asciiz "\n The distance squared is: "
        .double
        .text
main:       # Start of code section
    jal printst
    jal readint
    mov.d $f2, $f0  #x1
    jal printst
    jal readint
    mov.d $f4, $f0  #x2
    jal printst
    jal readint
    mov.d $f6, $f0  #y1
    jal printst
    jal readint
    mov.d $f8, $f0  #y2
    jal square
    jal printres
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
printst:
    li $v0, 4
    la, $a0, prompt
    syscall
    jr $ra
readint:
    li $v0, 7
    syscall
    jr $ra
square:

    la $s2, getdistance
    jalr $s3, $s2
    mul.d $f2, $f16, $f16
    jr $ra
getdistance:
    la $s0, getsides
    jalr $s1, $s0
    mul.d $f14, $f10, $f10
    mul.d $f16, $f12, $f12
    add.d $f16, $f16, $f14  #f16 becomes length of side
    jr $s3
getsides:
    sub.d $f10, $f4, $f2 #(x2-x1)
    sub.d $f12, $f8, $f6 #(y2-y1)
    jr $s1
printres:
    li $v0, 4
    la, $a0, result1
    syscall
    li $v0, 3
    mov.d $f0, $f10
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la, $a0, result2
    syscall

    li $v0, 3
    mov.d $f0, $f12
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la, $a0, result3
    syscall

    li $v0, 3
    mov.d $f0, $f2
    syscall

    jr $ra


# END OF PROGRAM
```

oh and also: the values that I enter (and end up getting a result of 1 for) are: x1:1 x2:2 y1:1 y2:2

Comment: oh and also: the values that I enter (and end up getting a result of 1 for) are:

x1:1
x2:2
y1:1
y2:2

Comment: A `1x1` square has area `1`. Try different values.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I also tried the values    `x1:3` ,`x2:7`,   `y1:5`,   `y2:9` and got the value of `4` for the area

Comment: I would expect f10=4 f12=4 f14=16 f16=32 and f2=1024. So there's two things to look at. 1) The algorithm for computing area should just be `area=width * height`. 2) You can step through the code and check the register values (and tell me why I'm wrong). Meanwhile I'll be afk for a bit.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your time! After looking at the registers, the numbers look like it should give me what I want, but still it's printing 4 as a final result. I'm using MARS, and while it's a long shot, I'm going to try the code on a computer with pcspim/mipster tomorrow and see if it's different at all

Comment: The [`print double` syscall expects the value to print in `$f12`](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html).

Comment: AHHHH! WHAT?! So, I moved the value of $f16 into $f12 and it worked. I can't explain it for the life of me though, I thought the`print double` syscall prints the value in `$f0` by default and i thought `mul.d $f2, $f16, $f16` squares $f16 and puts it into $f2, so when I moved `$f2` into `$f0` i was sure at worst it would print out the incorrect number due to a problem with my math.

Does `print double` always print `$f12`? thanks again!